# How to match shading to an overlapping mesh

Tags: animation, node-editor, lighting, shader-nodes

I'm really new to blender so please bare with me while I try explain this.

I want to animate this model that provided images on multiple meshes of different expressions of mouths and eyes that I want to be able to swap out to during animation. However im having trouble getting the shading of the overlapping mesh to match the model and am not sure how I would go about swapping them if its a case I cant hide the other meshes.

I would really appreciate your help :)

[image]
[image]